# How to set load more on top of RealmRecyclerView instead of bottom?

Tags: android, realm-list

RealmRecyclerView i want to load more data on swipe top instead of bottom how to set RealmRecyclerView  default load more on top.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load more data by swiping up in RecyclerView, I think, **SwipeRefreshLayout** is the good option. It is very easy to implement and also give efficient callback on swipe with loader. Please refer following code as a reference:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:overScrollMode="never" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Callback Method:

```
 swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // Refresh items
        }
    });
```

Hope this will help you.